# Taking Update in svn results in Encoded Data in whole project

Tags: asp.net-mvc, svn, tortoisesvn

I'm working in a project which uses `SVN`. **New SVN checkout** works fine and whenever i get an *update*, it builds successfully but when i run the project it shows this `Encoded Data` opening any page shows this same thing.

[image: Encoded Image]

Don't know what's happening. I tried changing the version of svn similar with the one in my team member's Pc where the project is running completely fine. but the Issue is still Same.

Initial version of svn

```
TortoiseSVN 1.9.2, Build 26806 - 64 Bit , 2015/09/22 18:33:30
Subversion 1.9.2, -release
apr 1.5.2
apr-util 1.5.4
serf 1.3.8
OpenSSL 1.0.2d 9 Jul 2015
zlib 1.2.8
SQLite 3.8.11.1
```

Downgraded version as the one in my team member's pc

```
TortoiseSVN 1.8.10, Build 26129 - 64 Bit , 2014/12/17 19:35:51
Subversion 1.8.11, -release
apr 1.5.1
apr-util 1.5.4
serf 1.3.8
OpenSSL 1.0.1j 15 Oct 2014
zlib 1.2.8
```

In Both version this issue is continuing. Please help if anyone have the solution or have ever faced such issue. Unable to find similar issue on google too.

Comment: You need to elaborate "but when i run the project it shows this Encoded Data". It is not clear what you mean by this.

Comment: The Data Showed in Image is what always seen. Nothing else in the project loads @AbhijeetNagre